# Computing probability mass function for a game

Tags: probability

> You are dealt one card at random from a full deck and your opponent is dealt 2 cards (without any replacement). If you get an Ace, he pays you \$10, if you get a King, he pays you \$5 (regardless of his cards). If you have neither an Ace nor a King, but your card is red and your opponent has no red cards, he pays you \$1. In all other cases you pay him \$1. Determine your expected earnings. Are they positive?

I was able to compute all but one of the probabilities, specifically $P(X=-1)$.
According to my text $P(X=-1)=1-\frac{2}{13}-\frac{11}{102}$.

What exactly were they counting for this outcome? 
I see that we want no Kings, no aces and no red cards, while our opponent also gets no red cards (or can they?).

$$P(X=10)=P(\text{You get an ace})=\frac{4}{52}$$
$$P(X=5)=P(\text{You get a King})=\frac{4}{52}$$
$$P(X=1)=P(\text{You get a red, and your opponent draws no reds})=\frac{(26-4)}{52}\frac{\binom{26}{2}}{\binom{51}{2}}$$

Comment: Show us how you computed the probabilities $\mathbb P(X=10)$, $\mathbb P(X=5)$ and $\mathbb P(X=-2)$.

Comment: I'll add those now.

Comment: So this is $\frac{11}{102}$. The probability that you get an ace or a king is $\frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{13}$. So the probability that none of these cases occur is $1-\frac{2}{13}-\frac{11}{102}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample Space:

- $A$: your card is ace
- $B$: your card is king
- $C$: your card is neither, but is red and both your opponent's cards are black
- $D$: all other cases

Probable Profits:

- $A$: $+10$ dollars
- $B$: $+5$  dollars
- $C$: $+1$  dollar
- $D$: $-1$  dollar

Probabilities:

- $P(A)=\binom{4}{1}/\binom{52}{1}=\frac{1}{13}$
- $P(B)=\binom{4}{1}/\binom{52}{1}=\frac{1}{13}$
- $P(C)=\binom{22}{1}/\binom{52}{1}\cdot\binom{26}{2}/\binom{51}{2}=\frac{11}{102}$
- $P(D)=1-P(A)-P(B)-P(C)=\frac{979}{1326}$

Expected Profit:

- $10\cdot\frac{1}{13}+5\cdot\frac{1}{13}+1\cdot\frac{11}{102}-1\cdot\frac{979}{1326}\approx52$ cents